# Add class to list item with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a list in asp.net like this:

```
<ul id="menu" runat="server">
  <li class="theMenu"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li class="theMenu"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li class="theMenu"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li class="theMenu"><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class to a list item when it is clicked using VB.net. So the user can see what menu item is the "active one" Just like it is done using jQuery:

```
$(".theMenu").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("Active");
});
```

How do you do this using VB.net???

Comment: You can't do that using VB.NET as this runs server side. The jQuery code runs client side so it allows you to do that. I suggest you look into using a web control to hold your list rather than using raw html

Comment: Yeah using asp:BulletedList right? But I don't how i should use that in VB to add a click event for all the child list elements of the bulletlist

Comment: @MattWilko Of course you _could_ do it from the VB.Net by converting `<ul>` to a server control... but it would be very inefficient.

Comment: Ok, this is possible to do, if your `ul` is generated in *vb* code and you do `Postback` manually. Or use server controls. 1st method is good when you have dynamic controls and you adapting them to `jQuery`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the jQuery. Really. Doing this from VB.Net means you have to cause a ***PostBack***, and that means completely re-creating your page on the server. You don't want to do that more than you have to. It adds load to your server, and adds latency to your page responses.

I suspect you also want to know later on which item is marked as active, so I also suggest combining this with an `<asp:HiddenField>` control, and add a line to the jQuery to also set the value of the hidden input created by the control. Later on, when you need to know in VB.Net which list item was marked as active, you can just check the Hidden Field.